# angular2 is it possible to share observable data with other components?

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-observables

I have a service that GETS a user via a RESTful api. It uses the [Observable](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html#!#-_observable-s) implementation.

I also have a parent component with 8 child components.

I want to know if and how I can make a single HTTP request in the parent component, to get the user and share it amongst its children components.

Here's the call to define user in the parent:

```
this.userApi.getUser(id)
        .subscribe(response => {this.user = response;},
                    error => error);
```

I've imported and injected the user model into the constructor() of each component like so:

```
constructor(public user: User){}
```

Once the **user** is defined in the parent, I have a button which fires a `console.log(user)` in the child components, it comes back as `undefined`.

Comment: Are you on NG2 RC4 or RC5?

Comment: Do post your implementation of getUser()

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make only a single HTTP request and share user data, create a **service**, which will *store* your user object. It would be available for each component (root and all childrens) in module.

Also you could use **ngRx** store idea - https://github.com/ngrx/store. Advantage of this solution is that you could subscribe user store in every fragment of application.