# How send data from master to the child component Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

## Detail

I am trying to get all product from api and show it in a component It Shows like this.

## Image

[image]
After this when I click on Name of the Product it redirect to another component to show its details. I developed and Api to get all product and in it all APi's are also in it response. Now I want to sent the APi's detail to detail component of the product without sending another request to get api response.

## Response

```
[
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "ApimId": "5746ebcfcd7c3209247edc40",
        "Name": "Atea Service Desk",
        "Description": "Service Desk and Operations",
        "SubscriptionRequired": false,
        "ApprovalRequired": false,
        "State": "published",
        "Apis": [
            {
                "Id": 1,
                "ApimId": "5746ba28804136004d040001",
                "Name": "Echo API",
                "Description": null,
                "ServiceUrl": "http://echoapi.cloudapp.net/api",
                "CreatedDate": "2016-09-20T11:37:09.162243+05:00",
                "CreatedBy": "LHR\\ahja",
                "UpdatedDate": "2016-09-20T11:37:09.162243+05:00",
                "UpdatedBy": "LHR\\ahja"
            },
            {
                "Id": 2,
                "ApimId": "574c167dcd7c3216c8c633b3",
                "Name": "Servicedesk and Operations",
                "Description": "Atea Servicedesk and Operations Internal API",
                "ServiceUrl": "http://dev-endpoint.atea.com/RFC",
                "CreatedDate": "2016-09-20T11:37:09.162243+05:00",
                "CreatedBy": "LHR\\ahja",
                "UpdatedDate": "2016-09-20T11:37:09.162243+05:00",
                "UpdatedBy": "LHR\\ahja"
            },
            {
                "Id": 3,
                "ApimId": "574eb044cd7c320600975d85",
                "Name": "Swagger Petstore",
                "Description": "This is a sample server Petstore server.  You can find out more about Swagger at [http://swagger.io](http://swagger.io) or on [irc.freenode.net, #swagger](http://swagger.io/irc/).  For this sample, you can use the api key `special-key` to test the authorization filters.",
                "ServiceUrl": "http://petstore.swagger.io/v2",
                "CreatedDate": "2016-09-20T11:37:09.162243+05:00",
                "CreatedBy": "LHR\\ahja",
                "UpdatedDate": "2016-09-20T11:37:09.162243+05:00",
                "UpdatedBy": "LHR\\ahja"
            },
            {
                "Id": 4,
                "ApimId": "574eb27fcd7c320600975d86",
                "Name": "Swagger Petstore API",
                "Description": "This API is design by Swagger.io",
                "ServiceUrl": "http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/api",
                "CreatedDate": "2016-09-20T11:37:09.162243+05:00",
                "CreatedBy": "LHR\\ahja",
                "UpdatedDate": "2016-09-20T11:37:09.162243+05:00",
                "UpdatedBy": "LHR\\ahja"
            }
        ],
        "CreatedDate": "2016-09-20T11:37:09.162243+05:00",
        "CreatedBy": "LHR\\ahja",
        "UpdatedDate": "2016-09-20T11:37:09.162243+05:00",
        "UpdatedBy": "LHR\\ahja"
    },
    {
        "Id": 3,
        "ApimId": "5746ba28804136004d060001",
        "Name": "Starter",
        "Description": "Subscribers will be able to run 5 calls/minute up to a maximum of 100 calls/week.",
        "SubscriptionRequired": false,
        "ApprovalRequired": false,
        "State": "notPublished",
        "Apis": [],
        "CreatedDate": "2016-09-20T11:37:09.7128066+05:00",
        "CreatedBy": "LHR\\ahja",
        "UpdatedDate": "2016-09-20T11:37:09.7128066+05:00",
        "UpdatedBy": "LHR\\ahja"
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "ApimId": "5746ba28804136004d060002",
        "Name": "Unlimited",
        "Description": "Subscribers have completely unlimited access to the API. Administrator approval is required.",
        "SubscriptionRequired": false,
        "ApprovalRequired": false,
        "State": "published",
        "Apis": [
            {
                "Id": 5,
                "ApimId": "5746ba28804136004d040001",
                "Name": "Echo API",
                "Description": null,
                "ServiceUrl": "http://echoapi.cloudapp.net/api",
                "CreatedDate": "2016-09-20T11:37:10.3071696+05:00",
                "CreatedBy": "LHR\\ahja",
                "UpdatedDate": "2016-09-20T11:37:10.3071696+05:00",
                "UpdatedBy": "LHR\\ahja"
            }
        ],
        "CreatedDate": "2016-09-20T11:37:10.3071696+05:00",
        "CreatedBy": "LHR\\ahja",
        "UpdatedDate": "2016-09-20T11:37:10.3071696+05:00",
        "UpdatedBy": "LHR\\ahja"
    }
]
```

Comment: Shared service, which will store your data or store. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39006427/angular2-is-it-possible-to-share-observable-data-with-other-components/39006693#39006693

Comment: @Input() is used to send data from one component to another. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Answer (score 0):

One idiom I find useful is the following:

1. Parent component owns the model. It is responsible for loading it and persisting it if necessary.
2. Parent component binds the model or a part of it to a child component's input property. The child displays it.
3. If the model is mutable, the child modifies the model in-place and notifies the parent with `EventEmitter` when that happens.
4. When the parent receives a notification from the child component it knows the model has changed.

In other words, the model object is shared between the parent and the child component objects.

In this context, the response is your model. The detail view component needs access to a part of the model. Bind that part of the model to an input property of detail view component.